# How to design a database table to enforce non-duplicate Unique Key records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, constraints

I have a SQL Server table:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+
| ID | CompanyID   | CompanyCode       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+
| 1  | 1           | AAAA-123          |
| 2  | 2           | BBBB-111          |
| 3  | 1           | AAAA-123          |
| 4  | 3           | CCCC-999          |
| 5  | 3           | CCCC-999          |
| 6  | 1           | AAAA-123          |
+----+-------------+-------------------+
```

The `ID` field is the PK.

The `CompanyID` and `CompanyCode` fields specify a unique company whereby a `CompanyID` will ALWAYS have the same `CompanyCode` (and vice versa) and no two Companies will ever have the same `CompanyID` and/or `CompanyCode`.

I would like to create a rule on the table that will never allow a record to be added to the table if/when a `CompanyCode` doesn't match an existing `CompanyCode` where the `CompanyID`'s match.

The following is an example of what I cannot allow to occur on the table:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+
| ID | CompanyID   | CompanyCode       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+
| 1  | 1           | AAAA-123          |
| 2  | 1           | BBBB-111          |<<<< This record should not be allowed
| 3  | 1           | AAAA-123          |
| 4  | 3           | CCCC-999          |
| 5  | 3           | CCCC-999          |
| 6  | 1           | AAAA-123          |
+----+-------------+-------------------+
```

Notice the record with `ID=2`, the `CompanyCode BBBB-111` doesn't match the existing record that has a `CompanyCode of AAAA-123`.

I want this rule to exist on the table somehow - i.e. I don't want this rule to be a business rule that queries and/or stored procedures have to manage.

I suppose you can say I'm wanting to enforce duplicate records (on `CompanyID` and `CompanyCode`) if and only if an existing `CompanyID` and/or `CompanyCode` exists in the table.

Is this possible to do at the table design level? Or am I stuck with having to manage this in my scripts?

**Update**

Although this isn't really pertinent to my OP, from the feedback I received, I suppose I should give a little background on the CompanyID/CompanyCode table design.

First off, this is just a mock table design to try to explain my question - my real table has nothing to do with companies.

Second, my real table is a middle-man between two web-services where Service1 creates a `DeviceID` and Service2 *collects* a `SerialNumber` that exists in a micro-device. Also, my real table contains many other columns that this middle-man server has to process.

One of the strange things about this middle-man service is that the table that I'm talking about has to allow NULLS for both the DeviceID and SerialNumber - it all depends on which Service sent a record first.... I'm am talking too much and going way off topic of my original question, but I thought I had to clarify my table example since I was getting much flak in regards to my breaking normalization.

Comment: Why is CompanyCode here and not in Company table?

Comment: This is like one of the early examples you get shown when learning normalization - if CompanyCode depends on CompanyID (and vice versa, in this case), there should be a table somewhere that represents that fact once, then only one of these keys should appear in the above table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this isn't the prettiest of code, but it does enforce the constraint, I think. The trick is to create an indexed view with two unique indexes defined on it:

```
create table dbo.ABC (
    Col1 int not null,
    Col2 int not null
)
go
create view dbo.ABC_Col1_Col2_dep
with schemabinding
as
    select Col1,Col2,COUNT_BIG(*) as Cnt
    from
        dbo.ABC
    group by
        Col1,Col2
go
create unique clustered index IX_Col1_UniqueCol2 on dbo.ABC_Col1_Col2_dep (Col1)
go
create unique nonclustered index IX_Col2_UniqueCol1 on dbo.ABC_Col1_Col2_dep (Col2)
go
```

Now we insert some initial data:

```
insert into dbo.ABC (Col1,Col2)
select 1,3 union all
select 2,19 union all
select 3,12
```

We can add another row with exactly the same values for `Col1` and `Col2`:

```
insert into dbo.ABC (Col1,Col2)
select 1,3
```

But if we pick a value for `Col2` that has been used for another `Col1`, or vice versa, we get errors:

```
insert into dbo.ABC (Col1,Col2)
select 2,3
go
insert into dbo.ABC (Col1,Col2)
select 1,5
```

---

The trick here was to observe that this query:

```
    select Col1,Col2,COUNT_BIG(*) as Cnt
    from
        dbo.ABC
    group by
        Col1,Col2
```

will only have one row for a particular `Col1` value, and only one row with a particular `Col2` value, provided that the constraint you're seeking to enforce has not been broken - but as soon as a non-matching row is inserted into the base table, this query returns multiple rows.

Answer (score 4):

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_name ON TableName(CompanyID, CompanyCode)
```

(assuming your table is named TableName).

However, you should be aware that this design violates the principle of database normalization.  A properly normalized database would have a separate table with only CompanyID and CompanyName fields.  You would then modify the table in your example to have only the CompanyID field; the CompanyCode would be "looked up" (using a VIEW) when needed.

This design has the following benefits:

1. It becomes literally impossible to have the same company ID with different names.
2. In the event a company changes its code, you only need to update one record in a single table which is error-proof and faster.
3. You save on storage.

It has a minor disadvantage in that you have to join in the Company table to get the code.  In relational databases that's not necessarily a real disadvantage (JOINing normalized data is what relational database are *for*), but you could eliminate even that by getting rid of CompanyID and using the code as the primary key for companies.  I would only consider this if the code is immutable (it won't change over time for a given company).

Comment: This will not work as a Unique Index will not allow multiple records to include the same CompanyID and CompanyCode. Notice how the example table in my OP includes more than one record with duplicate ID/Code.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you NOT store CompanyID and CompanyCode in the table.  Instead, you should have another table that stores 1 row for each CompanyId and also has it's corresponding code.  You can then set up a foreign key to makes sure the CompanyId in this table exists in the other table.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about making a rule to enforce this, but you are using two seperate foreign keys for the same thing ( that will always match up)... it would be a better idea to not have company code in this table at all and join it on a different table when you need the data, or redesign it in some other way

Answer (score 0):

You are violating 3rd normal form.  A non key is dependent on another non key.  CompanyCode is dependent on CompanyID.  The remedy as stated by others is to create a CompanyID, CompanyCode table where CompanyID is the PK.  Remove CompanyCode from your table and create FK relationship on ComanyID that points to you new table.    http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form